# restrict specific domain to enter in my email field using pattern

Tags: regex, html

I would like to restrict specific domain to enter in my email form field using pattern.

```
<input type='email' name='email' pattern='' required/>
```

i want to restrict "`mydomain.com`" not just `.com/.org/.in`, to enter in my email field.

How i can do that using reg expression?

I know how i can allow specific domain using reg. but reverse is not working for me.
sorry i m not good with reg expression

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to allow `something.com` but not `something.org`? Your question is not very clear as to what you want to be allowed and what you want to block.

Comment: yes i want to restrict only something.com.

Comment: every thing else match with email pattern is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative look aheads to handle validating against a string that is NOT followed by another string.

If you want to allow `something.com` but not `something.org` you can use `\w*\.(?!org)`.  This will match your `something.`, but will fail when it is followed by `org`.  To add more cases to this, you can add extra negative look aheads in as needed IE:  `\w*\.(?!com)(?!org)(?!net)`.

I did some testing using some examples [here](http://rubular.com/r/WBy5SpHu7O).

Comment: I just want to restrict "mydomain.com" everything else will be fine in email format.